# Why am I receiving a 500 error calling a URL with AJAX/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to pull in an external JSON file into my JavaScript code.  I created this JSON file with https://jsonserve.com/, which provided me with the URL (https://api.jsonserve.com/Xljpm).  When I call the URL in my JavaScript using an `XMLHttpRequest` object, I receive an error message.  Note: I'm using Visual Studio Code.  When I call a file containing the same JSON data from a local host server, everything works.  Can anyone tell me what's going on?

I tried executing this code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>JSON Giantess Data External</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    #output {
      background-color: blue;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="output" class="oput">Nothing</div>

  <script>
    var myContainer = "";
    var a = new XMLHttpRequest();

    a.open("GET", "https://api.jsonserve.com/Xljpml", true);
    //a.open("GET","data.json",true);
    a.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          console.log(obj[i]);
          myContainer += obj[i].giantess + " is growing to be " + obj[i].height + "!!!" + "<br>";
        } //end for loop
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myContainer;
        console.log(obj);
      } // end if
    } //end function
    a.send();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I received the following errors:

> ```
> AJAX_JSON.html:38     GET https://api.jsonserve.com/Xljpml 500
> (anonymous) @ AJAX_JSON.html:38
> VM181:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'I', "Internal S"... is not valid JSON
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at a.onreadystatechange (AJAX_JSON.html:29:19)
> a.onreadystatechange @ AJAX_JSON.html:29
> XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
> (anonymous) @ AJAX_JSON.html:38
> AJAX_JSON.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
> ```

Comment: I can't call that URL at all, seems like it is invalid. Start by making sure you can paste the URL into your browser and have it work. Example: https://api.jsonserve.com/cImaD8 <- works but https://api.jsonserve.com/wrongcImaD8 <- does not work and results in 500.

Comment: Verify your URL. Its odd that the system returns an 500 error. I would expect it to return something else.

Comment: My guess is a CORS error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#cross-site_xmlhttprequest

Comment: Also, why are you still working with XHTML 1.0 web pages? If there's no specific reason you are doing that, then your first two lines should be: `<!doctype html><html lang="en">` to signify that you are using HTML 5 and your `meta` tag should be: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: As you can see now that I've edited your question's code to be executable right here in Stack Overflow, that it does not return a 500 error. It returns an `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"` error, which means that the JSON is mal-formed. Have you validated the JSON?

Comment: @Igor The URL that the OP uses in the code (https://api.jsonserve.com/Xljpml) works just fine.

Comment: When you receive the results of an AJAX call, you should first check for `xhr.readystate === 4` , which means the response has been received, but you should then also check for `xhr.status === 200`, which means that the response was "OK". If you do that with your code, you'll see that it won't continue because you did receive a response, but the response was not "OK". I am not seeing any 500 Server Errors here.

Comment: If you look at the JS console (in the dev tools not the snippet) after running the snippet above, you can see the following error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.jsonserve.com/Xljpml' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: I verified CORS access prior to executing the code with a Test CORS app (https://webbrowsertools.com/test-cors/.  The results are below...Test CORS requests in your browser
Click the below buttons to test whether CORS requests are allowed or blocked by your browser CORS policy. In this test you can check policies for GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE and OPTIONS request types.

CORS is allowed for GET ✔
CORS is allowed for PUT ✔
CORS is allowed for POST ✔
CORS is allowed for HEAD ✔